# Open and exe and keeping it open - standalone exe opens just fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have an exe (a console app) that runs just fine when I double click on it. 
It sits in a folder on my local c:\ and I would like a c# winform button to open it, but it opens and closes. 
My code for winform button is as simple as follows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\myFolder\\myExe.exe");
```

What am I missing that would make my myExe.exe open just as if I was doubleclicking on the executable? (**opens and stays open**)
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: A likely cause is that the program is crashing. By any chance are you attempting to read a file that is located together with the .exe file? Try adding the parameter to set working folder.

Comment: Also, don't concatenate paths, use Path.Combine, but then to get your user folder, just use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), so your path should actually be `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "myFolder", "myExe.exe")`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You can't always use `Path.Combine` either. In this case yes but it cannot be used everywhere since the function is flawed. You cannot combine root paths with other folders it will return complete garbage.

Comment: @Fayaz its probably that 'myExe.exe' is either crashing or has completed its program and therefore closes quickly.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. Path.Combine is better than what I had but end results is the same. This exe does NOT read any file,it just opens. Let me try the set working folder.

Comment: Hex - sorry thats not the case. the exe I am trying to open is a completely standalone working exe. I can dclick and open it just fine.

Comment: @Franck Can you give an example of where it would return garbage?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - ** Your working directory parameter suggestion worked! **Thanks. Opens and stays open now. Appreciate the help. Thanks for everyone else also.I added             string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\users\" + Environment.UserName +  @"\path\");
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exeDir);  before my exe lines.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `var result = Path.Combine("d:", "test.txt");` this returns `d:text.txt` not `d:\test.txt`. the source code explicitly do not add the slash if it's a root path. No idea why they hardcoded this exception but it's there and it screwed me over twice already.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately the concept of a "rooted path" is a bit loose in that there are multiple ways it has been implemented in the past. For instance, if I drop to a command prompt, go to C: and enter C:\temp, create a file there, and then go to D:, anywhere on that disk, and use `type c:that-file`, it will type the file in C:\temp\that-file, because of the concept of "working folders", in which "C:" means "the working folder on C:" and "C:\" means "the root of C:". Path.IsPathRooted says "C:" is true, but unfortunately the rest is a bit of a mishmash. So yes.